# Sharepoint - Changing Database Server Name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql

Our Sharepoint Database Server will be moved to a new server, can someone please advise where we need to make the changes so that it points to the new server?

Any help will be highly appreciated as I'm new to Sharepoint 2010.

Regards

Comment: You should use the search, there is already topic like this one :
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45722/moving-the-sharepoint-2010-configuration-database-to-a-new-db-server

Comment: And another one on how to do this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/51429/34

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow this guide:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.14).aspx

or

1) Run this stsadm command:

> stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername oldservername -newservername
>   newservername

2) Rename and reboot server.

3) Enter Central Admin and look over all your Alternate Access Mappings (you’ll have to change to the new server name everywhere the old server name still shows).

4) I didn’t have this problem with 2010, but you might have to check and possibly reset your site collection admins. I wouldn’t be surprised if you’ll have to go over your host names in IIS in case you are using host headers also.

http://www.uccorner.com/67/sharepoint/rename-sharepoint-server-new-hostname/

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to use an Alias for the server Instance. so in the new server use alias which will reflect with old server instance.